# ldap_search() error: Success

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

This is my code:

```
$objLDAP = ldap_connect($_POST['host']);
$dn      = "OU=Users,DC=office,DC=example,DC=com";
if ($objLDAP)
{
    ldap_set_option($objLDAP, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_get_option($objLDAP,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,$error);
    print_r($error."<br/>");
    ldap_set_option($objLDAP, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_get_option($objLDAP,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,$error);
    print_r($error."<br/>");

    $objBind = ldap_bind($objLDAP);
    print_r($objBind."<br/>");

    $sr = ldap_search($objLDAP, $dn, "sn=*","sn") or die("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($objLDAP));
    print_r($sr."<br />");
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP)."<br />");

    $info = ldap_get_entries($objLDAP, $sr);
    print_r($info["count"]);
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP));
    exit();
}
```

Where $_POST['host'] is a valid hostname, and $dn is also a valid tree. However, when I run the program, I am getting

> 0
>   3
>   1
>   Success
>   Error in search query: Success

If I use ldap_errno, then I get "Error in search query: 0".

Can anyone please help me get more meaningful information back as to why I can't reach $info?

Thank you.

EDIT: 
Still debugging. If I change the line to:

```
$sr = ldap_search($objLDAP,$dn,"(dn=*)") or die("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($objLDAP);
```

Then I get

> Error in search query: Operations error

But the minute that I add in the fourth argument:

```
$sr = ldap_search($objLDAP,$dn,"(dn=*)","") or die("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($objLDAP);
```

Then I get:

> Error in search query: Success

ANOTHER EDIT:
Based on the comment below, I have taken the `or die()` out and simply continued with program flow. But I am still not getting any data in $info.

Code:

```
    ldap_set_option($objLDAP, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_get_option($objLDAP,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,$error);
    print_r($error.": LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS<br/>");
    ldap_set_option($objLDAP, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_get_option($objLDAP,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,$error);
    print_r($error.": LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION<br/>");

    $objBind = ldap_bind($objLDAP);
    print_r($objBind.": objBind<br/>");
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP).": ldap_bind error<br/>");
    $sr = ldap_search($objLDAP,"OU=Users,DC=office,DC=example,DC=com","(sn=*)","");
    print_r($sr.": search result<br />");
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP).": ldap_search error<br />");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($objLDAP, $sr);
    print_r($info["count"].": number of entries returned<br />");
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP.": ldap_get_entries error<br />"));
    exit();
```

Result:

> 0: LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS
>   3: LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION
>   1: objBind
>   Success: ldap_bind error
>   : search result
>   Success: ldap_search error
>   : number of entries returned

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an LDAP-question but a PHP-question.

Your statement is `ldap_search() or die()`. But what does it do:

The `or die()` causes the script to die if the part before the `or` is `false`. But `ldap_search` does not return a boolean value but a resource. And due to PHPs dynamic nature that resource is automaticaly converted to `false`. So even if your search returns something usefull you will **always** run into the `or die()`-part.

I think what you want to do is something like the following:

```
$sr = ldap_search($objLDAP, $dn, "sn=*","sn");
if (ldap_errno($objLDAP)) {
    print_r($sr."<br />");
    print_r(ldap_error($objLDAP)."<br />");
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer. However, even without the `or die()`, I am not getting any data from the search. `$info` is never populated. I will edit my question to further reflect that.

Thank you for explaining that any answer is converted to `false`. That is very helpful information.